# ragged left in Plain TeX

Tags: justification

I typeset Hebrew using Plain XeTex and BIDI. Past a certain font size full justification does not work (no hyphenation).

Thus I would to have *right justification and a ragged left in Plain TeX*. There is \raggedright, but no \raggedleft.

One of the answers was for doubly ragged and centred, but this is not what I want.

Answer (score 2):

You can define your own `\raggedleft` by taking the definition of `\raggedright` and replacing `\rightskip` with `\leftskip`:

```
 \def\raggedleft{\leftskip=0pt plus2em \spaceskip .3333em \xspaceskip .5em\relax}
```

Afterwards, `\leftskip` has a stretch component (`plus 2em`), so the text is ragged un the left. Setting `\spaceskip` and `\xspaceskip` is used to make sure that the interword space is not stretchable, such that inter word spaces on different lines have the same width.

Comment: I in fact thought of redefining \raggedright, but there was only one problem---which I have had since I started using \TeX in the 1980s---where does one find these definitions??  You seem to be/have been studying mathematics so in exchange for your answer I can offer you my "pick a number" trick to impressive people even more than you do already: http://web.ncf.ca/en493/ ==> pick a number

Comment: @morrisroger The best source for all plain TeX definitions is the TeXbook. For example on page 101 you find an explenation why the definition makes sense and Appendix B contains the annotated code of the format. If you do not have a copy of the TeXbook, you can find all the plainTeX definitions in the source of the plain TeX format, the file `plain.tex`. Another way is to run `tex` on the command line and entering `\show\raggedright`, then `TeX` answers with the current definition of `\raggedright`.

Comment: But on modern TeX installations, `texdef` is the most simple way to find definition: Run `texdef raggedright` to get the definition of `raggedright`. You can also run `texdef --tex xetex raggedright` to show the definition from plain *Xe*TeX (the same as the plain TeX one) or `texdef --tex xelatex raggedright` to see the LaTeX version. It might be interesting to read the help (`texdef -h`), there you find a lot of other features which make `texdef` incredibly powerful, especially when looking for LaTeX definitions.